# PostGIS: floating point representation problem with ST_AsText

Tags: python, postgis, well-known-text, regular-expression

I have a table with geometries, all with about 13 digits of accuracy. While trying to represent them with ST_AsText though, most vertices come out in decimal notation, but some come out in scientific notation. Problem is, I'm extracting these geometries in a python script and parsing them to arrays through regular expression, and the e- notation is screwing this up.

This does not happen frequently, but once is enough to halt the entire process (or more precisely, generate incorrect results for the remainder of the geometry). I have tried truncating the coordinate values to less digits, but it matters not, the same vertices get modified by some reason. ST_AsEWKT turns up the same problem, as expected.

Why is this happening? Any solutions I could use to either solve this problem or work around it?

Comment: There are talks about that functionality for 2.3. https://github.com/postgis/postgis/pull/94

Comment: So nice to know I'm not the only one advocating the need for a solution to this! Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to update your script and use ST_AsGeoJSON().
You can also choose the number of digits with this function.

http://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html